# What is the toroidal device that Cassian is carrying to Jedha?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one, object-identification

In *Rogue One*, while Cassian and Jyn try to contact someone who could take them to Saw Gerrera, we can notice that Cassian is carrying a backpack with a big round device with a hose tied to it. The device looks apparently heavy and has a toroidal shape. What is the function of that device? Is it a kind of a comm device? I'm asking the question because I had the challenge to recreate the aforementioned device for one of my dioramas and I still have no clue about what I did build.

[image: Still image from Star Wars Rogue One]

Here a picture of Cassian's backpack I made for my diorama with the unknown device.

[image: Picture of Cassian's backpack]

Comment: I don't think it's described anywhere. It was just a [greeble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greeble). That being said, it vaguely resembles a [coolth backpack](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Coolth_backpack) (I suspect more by coincidence than design), so maybe it's one of those